# Connected sum of $n$ $\mathbb{R}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does anyone know a way of computing the fundamental group of the connected sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}P^n$?

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Seifert Van-Kampen theorem?

Comment: i have no clue how to compute the general case though.

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as $\mathbb RP^n$ connect sum itself, perhaps you should think of it as $S^n$ connect-sum many $\mathbb RP^n$ ?   This way all the discs are in one common manifold and it will be easier to identify the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$, it is $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

For $n=2$, we have $\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2 \simeq \textit{Klein Bottle}$, so $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$.

For $n \geq 3$, according to [Fundamental group of the connected sum of manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199762/fundamental-group-of-the-connected-sum-of-manifolds) the fundamental group of a connected sum of $\geq 3$-dimensional manifolds is the free product of the fundamental groups, so $\pi_1(\#_{i=1}^n \mathbb{R}P^n) \cong *_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}/2$.